# Shutdown launcher withouth password

Tags: password, shutdown, hibernate, visudo

I added new launcher to panel using this command for shutdown: gksu telinit 0

When I wanted to get rid of constant inserting of password, I did not succeed. I opened visudo and added line "username" ALL = NOPASSWD: sbin/telinit 0

...but it doesn't work

I succeded with hibernate launcher in similar way - with adding line in visudo: "username" ALL = NOPASSWD: etc/acpi/hibernate.sh

What am I doing wrong with shutdown line in visudo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should  be able to use `poweroff` to turn off a system.

Run this command:

```
sudo visudo
```

Add this line near the bottom (before the `#includedir` line), or edit an existing line:

```
USERNAME ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/poweroff
```

(replace `USERNAME` with your username)

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Change your launcher to use the `sudo /sbin/poweroff` command.

To additionally make this work for reboot, add `/sbin/reboot` to the `NOPASSWD:` line above.

Comment: Thank you...that worked...what would be command for restart?

Comment: @mo That would be `reboot`. I'll edit my answer.